# Meaning of "intercepted"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-meaning

Tia tries to run over to help her husband, but is **intercepted** by two police officers.

Does "**intercepted**" imply that the police officers are being physical with her? In other words does it have the same meaning as "**held back**"?

Tia tries to run over to help her husband, but is **held back** by two police officers.

Comment: I don't think ***intercepted*** here implies any physical context whatsoever. I'd be *slightly* more inclined to assume actual physical restraint if the verb was ***accosted***, but to my mind, ***intercept*** here matches the full OED's definition 4: ***To cut off** (one thing) from (another), or (**elliptically**) **from sight, access,** etc.* The officers moved to place themselves between Tia and her husband so she couldn't get to him. There's no reason to assume either of them actually *touched* her (one might have held up a hand "palm forward" as a restraining gesture).

Comment: (Perhaps she was ***waved back*** rather than ***held back*** or ***pushed back***.)

Answer (score -1):

When I read your sentence I immediately pictured 2 police officers grabbing the woman's two arms. Something like that:

[image]

[WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/intercept.html#C0-2)'s definition clearly indicates that yes,  "intercepted" implies that the police officers were being physical with her:

> To grab (someone), usually aggressively, to stop them or bring them to ground

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/intercept) Dictionary states that

> If you intercept someone or something that is travelling from one
> place to another, you stop them before they get to their destination.
>
> - Gunmen ***intercepted*** him on his way to the airport.